# Question about the abelian extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, abelian-groups, galois-extensions

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is it true that if $K$ is either totally real or CM-field, then the Galois group $G(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian?

If not, what if the hypothesis is changed to "irreducible" polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Actually, i'm wonder about when is the Galois group $G(K/\mathbb{Q})$ (of $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with splitting field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) abelian?

I would be grateful if you could give me any advice or references. Thank you.

Comment: No, consider for instance $x^3-4x+1$. It's irreducible, but its discriminant is not a rational square, so the splitting field has Galois group $S_3$.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you for comment. One thing that the first question is still not clear to me. Is there an example for non-irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Sure, take something like $(x^3-4x+1)^2$, or $x(x^3-4x+1)$. Do you perhaps want to put some condition on this reducible $f$ to make this less trivial?

Comment: I believe that's correct. Unfortunately, I don't have time to elaborate now, but if you could insert those questions into the actualy body of the question, I could later (or maybe someone else will in a meanwhile) add a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kronecker-Weber Theorem says that the finite abelian extensions of $\mathbb Q$ (so finite Galois extensions having abelian Galois group) are precisely the subfields of cyclotomic extensions (so those extensions given by adjoining a root of unity).